# Replace partial data in an element using xquery

Tags: replace, xquery

I am trying to replace partial data of an element with empty string in xquery. I have **ticket details xml** and **email to remove xml** with me. Now i need to form an xquery which would modify the **ticket details xml** by removing the email ids that are there in the element EmailIdToDelete available in second xml from the element EmailId available in first xml and give me the **expected output**. The xquery version used is not latest. I guess it is very old. Need to check that.

Could someone please help me with this?

**Ticket Details xml:**

```
<TicketDetails>
<EmailInformation>
<EmailId>test1@aaa.com;test2@aaa.com;test3@aaa.com;test4@aaa.com;test5@aaa.com;test6@aaa.com;test7@aaa.com;test8@aaa.com</EmailId>
</EmailInformation>
</TicketDetails>
```

**Email to remove xml:**

```
<Details>
<EmailDetails>
<EmailIdToDelete>test2@aaa.com</EmailIdToDelete>
<EmailIdToDelete>test5@aaa.com</EmailIdToDelete>
<EmailIdToDelete>test8@aaa.com</EmailIdToDelete>
</EmailDetails>
</Details>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<TicketDetails>
<EmailInformation>
<EmailId>test1@aaa.com;test3@aaa.com;test4@aaa.com;test6@aaa.com;test7@aaa.com;</EmailId>
</EmailInformation>
</TicketDetails>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `tokenize` on `;` and then simply compare and only select the values without a match in the second document:

```
<EmailId>{string-join(tokenize(TicketDetails/EmailInformation/EmailId, ';')[not(. = $remove/Details/EmailDetails/EmailIdToDelete)], ';')}</EmailId>
```

where `$remove` is the second document e.g. `let $remove := doc('remove.xml')` or an external parameter:

```
declare variable $remove as document-node() external := document {
<Details>
<EmailDetails>
<EmailIdToDelete>test2@example.com</EmailIdToDelete>
<EmailIdToDelete>test5@example.com</EmailIdToDelete>
<EmailIdToDelete>test8@example.com</EmailIdToDelete>
</EmailDetails>
</Details>    
};


<TicketDetails>
<EmailInformation>
<EmailId>{string-join(tokenize(TicketDetails/EmailInformation/EmailId, ';')[not(. = $remove/Details/EmailDetails/EmailIdToDelete)], ';')}</EmailId>
</EmailInformation>
</TicketDetails>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuPs2

Comment: I was thinking of taking both the input and the IDs to be removed in separate arrays and then eliminate the unwanted ones. Your answer worked perfectly Martin. Thanks a lot!